# HighCharts/HighStocks: Pie graph with Highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was wondering if there was anyway to plot data in a Highstocks pie graph and take advantage of the Highstocks data selector.

I have the following data

```
["Firefox", "2013-09-24", 5], ["Firefox", "2013-09-25", 10], ["Firefox", "2013-09-26", 15],
["IE", "2013-09-24", 1], ["Firefox", "2013-09-25", 2], ["Firefox", "2013-09-26", 3],
["Safari", "2013-09-24", 20], ["Firefox", "2013-09-25", 10], ["Firefox", "2013-09-26", 30]
```

I want this data to be plotted as a pie graph. When I select the date range of 9/24/2013-9/25/2013, I want the pie graph to be drawn using the totals of that date range.
Firefox: 15
IE: 3
Safari: 30

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible, but highcharts / highstock use timestamps (time in miliseconds) instead of data like "2013-09-24". But you can prepare your own custom selector which will show/hide related points by [setVisible](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setVisible%28%29) function.

Comment: Yes, sorry I know the timestamps are not in that format, I just wrote it like that in the question to make it easier to read. Is there no way I can take advantage of the slider function to aid in a redraw?

Comment: Defaulty it is not possible, pie chart is not compatible with highstock. So only what you can do is prepare your own selector, as I mentioned above.